# jQuery Div On Click Load External Url Performance Slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 js click function. Both function is to load external url.

Here is the JS script:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".activity_div").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".loading").show();
        $(".content_default").hide();
        $(".activity_div").css('color', '#5da8a1');
        $(".default_div").css('color', '#858585');

        $("#content_activity").load("load_activity.php?uid=" + ID, function()
        {
            $('#content_activity').show();
        });
    }

    $(".default_div").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");

        $(".loading").show();
        $(".content_activity").hide();
        $(".default_div").css('color', '#5da8a1');
        $(".activity_div").css('color', '#858585');

        $("#content_default").load("load_notification.php?uid=" + ID, function()
        {
            $('#content_default').show();
        });
    }
}
```

Actually the function is running OK. But facing the problem when I click the div alternately and quickly. The problem come, Web Browser(Mozilla) performance to be slow.

How can I fix that code?

Comment: What is the problem that you are running into?

Comment: Every time you click, It has to hit the server and return a response. You may want to leverage some sort of server side caching to speed this up.

It's hard to provide specific help without trying it out and seeing the response time from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how long it takes to load the content on this line:

```
$("#content_activity").load("load_activity.php?uid=" + ID, function()
```

using the network tab (CTRL+SHIFT+S)